# How to get wsdl file from private server on azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, soap, azure-web-app-service

I want to import the wsdl from some private server on azure. They *(server owners)* have issued us a certificate and also have whitelisted the outbound IP's of my Azure service. I added private key certificate on my Azure service.

After that I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-soap-api) and created a new API management instance and tried to import the wsdl file from their server URL but its giving me following error "*Unable to download specified file. Please ensure the URL is valid and file is publicly accessible.*"

It was quiet easy if I had a VM and with whitelisted IP's. I could've used SoapUI testing tool on the whitelisted IP machine in which I can provide the p12/pkc certificate as well, but I'm not able to do it on azure. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify which outbound IP was white listed? The web app's or API Management instance's? Also, where are you using web app or asp.net core here?

Comment: Outbound IP's are of Azure service not of API management instance. No, as of now I'm not using asp.net core. I'm planning to use once I get the wsdl file.

Comment: Could you confirm which azure service?

Comment: Azure App service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the outbound IPs of your App Service have been whitelisted, the request to the private server can only come from there. Both APIM (and the CORS proxy used to load the WSDL) have different IPs.

One way to approach this would be to have a simple proxy app on your App Service which proxies requests to the private server (with some security of course) and use that URL to load the WSDL. Also, in APIM, you would have set the backend of your imported API to the proxy endpoint.

Another approach would be to whitelist your APIM IP instead but loading the WSDL would still fail because of the CORS proxy used. In this case, you could either

- Acquire the WSDL file manually and upload it
- [Create an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually) in APIM which just returns the WSDL

Also, do note that the outbound IPs for both [APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ip-addresses#changes-to-the-ip-addresses) and [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change) may change with specific configuration changes.